# Can macros mimic void returning functions by casting to void?

Tags: c, macros, void, c89

So... I have macros, that has "SET" functionality and shall mimic a function, that would return void. I could use a do {...} while(0) construct to implement this behavior, but is it legal, and if so is it implementation defined behavior to cast something to void to implement this? (according the very words of the different versions of the C standards, most important for me: C89 still)

More specific:
Are the following functions/macros are behaving similar (including being legal and provoking compile time errors when used as rvalue)?

```
  void setFunction(int * const pVar, const int intvalue) /* as function */ 
  {
        *pVar = intvalue;
        return;
  }

  #define SET_MACRO_DW(pVar,intvalue) \
          do { \
               *(pVar) = (intvalue); \
             } while (0)

  #define SET_MACRO_C2V(pVar,intvalue) \
          ((void) (*(pVar) = (intvalue)))


  void test()
  {
       int target;
       int value = 17;
       int retDummy;

       setFunction(&target, value); /* ok */
       SET_MACRO_DW(&target, value); /* ok */
       SET_MACRO_C2V(&target, value); /* ok? */

       retDummy = setFunction(&target, value); /* CT error/warning */
       retDummy = SET_MACRO_DW(&target, value); /* CT syntax error */
       retDummy = SET_MACRO_C2V(&target, value); /* ??? */
       return;

  }
```

Comment: Why can't you test it? Or why don't you just expand the macro in each example and see if it makes sense?

Comment: Why are you used a construct as `do {} while(0)`. It means nothing!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini This construct ist AFAIK common to encapsulate multiple instructions within a macro, but preserving the calling context with an semicolon at the end. The "do" will allow to execute (multiple instruction) macros, in IF-clauses that like "if(...) macro(x,y);" In my context it will prevent that the macro can legally used as lvalue.

Comment: But I think that to avoid the use as lvalue you might use: `#define SET_MACRO_DW(pVar,intvalue) (*(pVar) = (intvalue));`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I lack the toolchain for testing the different C standard documents for this case; I even lack the toolchain to review them. :-)

Comment: @MarkA.Again, this question is not about macros, it's a question just about rvalues. The macro is expanded literally.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Accepted. Thanks you for pointing that out. Please feel free to answer (or link, if I am to stupid to find the right answer already given) the rvalue issue in context of my question, prefered by also citing the C standards.

Comment: @MarkA. In other words, it is a clever trick used to justify bad coding style. Because such macros are only useful to people who omit braces after control statements, and are therefore prone to write bugs related to lack of braces. I would strongly recommend to always use braces instead, which will turn the `do while(0)` trick completely redundant. See the famous "Apple goto fail" if someone out there still thinks omitting braces is a jolly good idea.

Comment: @Lundin For any common case you are totally correct. The `do while(0)` is a redunant to braces, where it is normally used. And I asked this question find better solutions. But with yesterdays answer of Armali, there IS a case were this construct is preferable.

Comment: @MarkA. Not really, that answer isn't all that accurate. You should go looking at the assignment operator. In 6.5.16.1 the various cases of allowed assignments are listed. None of them allows the right operand to be of type void, simple as that. So you'll get just as much of a compiler error in all of those cases.

Comment: @Lundin You are right. I haven't read the constraints in the sub chapters. Thank you for pointing out. That means all constructs are equally constraint violations by C89 - I assume also in the newer versions?

Comment: @MarkA. I don't believe this part of the standard has changed much since C89.

Comment: @Lundin Hm... leaves only one application I didn't think of yet. What about using it in an call as function parameter?

Comment: @Lundin found it myself: Also constraint violation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the following functions/macros are behaving similar (including
>   being legal and provoking compile time errors when used as rvalue)?

They are behaving similar when used correctly (i. e. not in an assignment) and probably, but not necessarily, when used as an rvalue (see below).

They are of course legal only when used correctly.

Concerning compile time errors, the Standards from C89 to C11 have very similar wording in section *Environment / Conceptual models / Translation environment / Diagnostics* as in C89 (bold text added in C99):

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) for every
>   translation unit that contains a violation of any syntax rule or
>   constraint**, even if the behavior is also explicitly
>   specified as undefined or implementation-defined**. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other
>   circumstances.

Now, when using your function/macros as an rvalue, we have two cases.

1. `SET_MACRO_DW()`
   The `do` `while` statement it expands to is in an assignment expression clearly a violation of the syntax rule *assignment-expression*, hence a diagnostic message has to be produced.
2. `setFunction()` and `SET_MACRO_C2V()`
   These are *void expressions*. As an rvalue they don't violate any syntax rule, so the question is whether there is a violation of any constraint. The following wording in section *Language / Conversions / Other operands / `void`* didn't change from C89 to C11.

   > The (nonexistent) value of a *void expression* (an expression that has
   >   type `void`) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit
   >   conversions (except to `void`) shall not be applied to such an
   >   expression.

   Also, the Standards have very similar wording as

   > In this Standard, "shall" is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, "shall not" is to be interpreted as a prohibition.
   >   …
   >   If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

   Now, I couldn't decide whether the above requirement for a *void expression* constitutes a *constraint*, so I asked [What are the Constraints in Standard C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409241/what-are-the-constraints-in-standard-c)
   The conclusion is that the above is not a constraint in the sense of the standard, hence <strike>on the usage as an rvalue an error message is not guaranteed (albeit one should be produced by every sane compiler) and</strike> the use results in *undefined behavior*. But there's still the constraint in section *Language / Expressions / Assignment operators / Simple assignment*:

   > One of the following shall hold: …

   where none of the following holds, hence we have a constraint violated and an error message is guaranteed even though the behavior is explicitly undefined.

So, `SET_MACRO_DW()` is the most plain and fool-proof construct of the three you presented.

Comment: Lundin pointed out, that at least using it in assignments is a constraint violation of the assignment operator

Comment: Well spotted - I'll correct the answer accordingly.

Comment: I fear you may have to correct your answer more exhaustively: As it is guaranteed that a diagnostic will be raised, the behavior is no longer UB. UB and constraint violations on the same issue are mutually exclusive (if I interpret the definition of UB right). In this case: As we can't assign it without raising a diagnostic we have not used a void expression in any way. :-)

Comment: :-) I'm afraid you missed the bold text cited from section _Diagnostics_; it suggests (to me, at least) that UB and constraint violations are not mutually exclusive. In this case: By violating a constraint, we raised a diagnostic, and we did this exactly by that very use of a void expression. (Hadn't we used a void expression, the constraint wouldn't be violated.)

Comment: hmm... I really need the C99 standard. :-) You have a point here. And even if I may be right for C89 (have to check tomorrow), the passage you cited makes pretty clear that the standard does not constraint a constraint violation to be not UB... until I know better I now think you are right.

If this is the full truth, I have even more responsibility analyzing warnings and informations, as UB can only exist in a compiled program,   and I assumed that constraint violations will cause an compile time error (diagnostic == error).

Comment: In C99 appears the _NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable
results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or
execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)._