# pass value by reference doesn't work after 2nd pass in c

Tags: c

```
   int main()
   {
      int *x = 100;

      display(&x);

   }

   display(int *m)
   {
      show(&m);
   }

   show(int *m)
   {
      printf("%d",*m)`; 
   }
```

output should be 100.But it is not showing that

Comment: Surely your compiler is telling you something...

Comment: Remove `&` sign from anywhere.  `int *` is an address, no need to `&`.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference, it is strictly pass-by-value! A pointer is a first-class object.

Comment: Guess what: `&m` is not of `int *` type.

Comment: int *x = 100; Are you sure that you know what a Pointer is/does?

Comment: `int *x = 100;` is not a valid form of simple assignment. This code is not allowed to compile without diagnostics. If you got no warnings or errors, you need a better compiler.

Comment: @Lundin: Sure the compiler shall generate a diagnostic for assigning an integer to a pointer? (Of course it **should** and the code - as intended - invokes UB).

Comment: @Olaf Yes I'm sure because I believed this wasn't required myself until someone on SO pointed it out to me. 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment is followed by the text [constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409241/what-are-the-constraints-in-standard-c) (particularly, see the answer by Jerry Coffin), meaning that the following text is normative and code that does not fit the rules of simple assignment is a constraint violation, for which a conforming compiler must generate a diagnostic.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks for the info. I never compile without ca. half a dozen warning-options, so I was not sure. Just tried with gcc 4.8.4. Indeed it warns without any additional option (no `-Wall` etc.) and for all three version of the C standard. Nitpick: the code does not have an assignment, but an initialiser. So for the complete chain of proof we need 6.7.9p1 (`assignment-expression`), too. :-)

Comment: @Olaf Doesnt matter if it is initialization or assignment, see 6.7.9p11. "the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply"

Comment: @Lundin: That was obvious. It just was missing.

Answer (score 4):

You are messing up the types. Se comments below:

```
   int main()
   {
      int *x = 100;   // x is a "pointer to int" (with bad assignment)

      display(&x);    // Since you use &x you are passing a "pointer to a pointer to int"

   }

   display(int *m)    // but the function just expects a "pointer to int"
   {
      show(&m);       // Here you do the same
                      // m is a "pointer to int"
                      // so &m is a "pointer to pointer to int"
   }

   show(int *m)       // but the function just expects a "pointer to int"
   {
      printf("%d",*m)`; 
   }
```

To fix it do the following:

```
   int main()
   {
      int x = 100;   // x is a "int"  (i.e. no *)

      display(&x);    // Passing a "pointer to int"

   }

   display(int *m)  
   {
      show(m);       // Just pass a "pointer to int" (i.e. no &) as 
                     // m is already "pointer to int"
   }

   show(int *m)
   {
      printf("%d",*m)`; 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

- `int *x = 100;` means "x is a variable that references the memory cell at address 100". That makes close to no sense to assign a pointer address manually in your code because... why would you even do that? You would most probably get runtime errors if you tried to modify the variable value later in your code. You'd better just make `x` a plain integer rather than a pointer.
- `&x` is the address of the variable x. With `int *x`, when calling `display(&x)`, you call a function with signature `display(int** m)`. This is not your current `display` function. Call `display(x)` instead if you want the types to match. If you decide to actually make `x` a plain integer, then you can keep the `display(&x)` call.
- Same as above, if you want to call `show(&m)` with `m` being an `int*` (as your `display` signature specifies), then your `show` signature should be `show(int** m)`. Just call `show(m)` instead.
- Your two functions lack return types in their signatures. It may compile with some compilers, but I'm not sure this is allowed by the C norm.
- Make sure your two functions are forward-declared if you want to put the body after the `main` function.
- Even so, the type mismatches in your function calls should not compile.

Good try, but you should document yourself more, there are tons of examples with basic pointer usage out there!

Answer (score 0):

In the display function, you already have a pointer as an input, you do not need to take the address again. You can just pass the pointer on the the `show` function.

```
display(int *m)
{
   show(m);
}
```