# Integer constant not in the representable range

Tags: c, constants, language-lawyer

Based on this (C11 6.4.4/2):

> **Constraints**
>
> 2 Each constant shall have a type and the value of a constant shall be
>   in the range of representable values for its type.

is writing this correct:

```
unsigned long long int a=18446744073709551615;
```

as the integer constant (which is a **decimal constant**) type can not be `unsigned`. So the value is not in the representable range.

What happens exaclty ? the value is not in the representable range of decimal constant. ?

If I am right, the integer constant may be extended if there is no type in the correpondant list that could represent the constant. 
The problem here is that the decimal constants can be extended only to a signed integer constants. 
So the number `18446744073709551615` has no type.

How could be the conversion  from **no type** to `unsigned long long int` ?

Comment: `ULONG_MAX` is the value you want to check

Comment: try `unsigned long long int a=18446744073709551615ULL;`

Comment: Add a `u`  `18446744073709551615u`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know that I want to know the behavior of the example above. (by the way you can use `u` and save the extra `LL`)

Comment: @Sabrina a single `u` is sufficient.   No `l` needed.  The compiler will use `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` as needed.  No need to force the constant wider than needed.

Comment: @chux +1 you are right !

Comment: Most developers do not care too much about adding the suffix and some never heard about it so how could be such behavior.

Comment: Read document about literal.

Comment: Note : pre-C99, decimal constants could be `unsigned long`.

Comment: What happens exaclty ? the value is not in the representable range of decimal constant. ?

Comment: @Sabrina When `long long` is 64-bit, `... =18446744073709551615;` is UB AFAIK.

Comment: @chux your reference please.

Comment: @chux this is a constraint, so it is a constraint violation

Comment: @chux why it is UB ?

Comment: "So the number ... has no type." in contradiction with "If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value. If all of the types in the list for the constant are signed, the extended integer type shall be signed."

Comment: @seb: The implementation is not required to have extended integer types, and many do not. So it is not a contradiction. The number might also be valid because the implementation's `long long int` is wide enough to represent that number; no contradiction there, either.

Comment: @rici It's certainly an invalid assertion; invalidity doesn't mean incorrect, it means there are possibilities where it is incorrect.

Comment: There is another language-lawyer thread somewhere about whether constraint violations are UB but I can't seem to find it using the search feature (maybe it got deleted)

Comment: @rici Are you refering to some compiler extensions by 128-bit artihemtic?

Comment: @M.M.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409241/what-are-the-constraints-in-standard-c is where I pulled the reference to DR 33 from

Comment: @Sabrina: I'm referring to 6.2.5 para 4: "There may also be
implementation-defined extended signed integer types"

Comment: @rici it will be a problem treating that type without violating the standard. Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: @sabrina: Effectively, the standard guarantees that 2^63-1 is representable. Signed integers larger than that *may* be representable, either because the implementation's integer types are wider than the minimum or because the implementation has extended integer types that are wider than 63 bits. A programmer is allowed to make use of their knowledge about the implementation. The programs thus produced do not *violate the standard*. However, they are *non-portable*. See Sect 4 para 7 and footnote 5: "Conforming programs may depend upon nonportable features of a conforming implementation."

Comment: This could be an answer to this question. Now I can see your point. It can be resumed to implementation-defined. If the platform has no extended integer types suitable to represent that then the constraint will be violated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on two long comments threads which eventually reached some kind of conclusion, I'll hazard this answer to the question:

> Is writing this correct:
>   `unsigned long long int a=18446744073709551615;`

Answer: **Maybe; it's implementation dependent.**

In a conforming implementation, a `long long int` must be capable of representing numbers up to the minimum `LLONG_MAX`, which is +9223372036854775807 (2<sup>63</sup>−1) (§5.2.4.2.1). Since the number in question is somewhat larger than that, there is no guarantee that it will fit in a `long long`, and therefore no guarantee that it is representable. If it is not representable, the program is in violation of a constraint (in §6.4.4.1), and the implementation must respond to a constraint violation by producing a diagnostic message.

However, a given implementation is completely free to make `long long int` a wider type. Alternatively, it can take advantage of §6.2.5 para 4 ("There may also be implementation-defined extended signed integer types") to define another type, say `int128_t`, which is wider than a `long long int`. So the number may be representable in a conforming implementation, and using the program with such an implementation is completely valid, as indicated by §4 paragraph 7, which states that a conforming program "is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation". So a programmer is allowed to make use of their knowledge about what is acceptable to the implementation they are using, and if the integer constant is acceptable to their implementation, then no diagnostic is necessary.

§4 also defines a stronger category of programs, *strictly conforming programs* (paragraph 5), which should be portable between all conforming implementations. The above integer constant is not strictly conforming, so the validity of the program is implementation-dependent.

On a practical note, both clang and gcc accept the program, but not because they have wider integers. The diagnostic produced is:

> warning: integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned
>         [-Wimplicitly-unsigned-literal]

which is sufficient to comply with the standard, and which specifies the behaviour they are about to take. Once the required diagnostic is produced, the C standard no longer applies. The programmer has been warned, and if the implementation still produces an executable, it is up to it to document what that executable does. There is no difference between constraint violations, as in this question, or syntax errors: if a conforming compiler wishes to accept a syntax not defined in the C standard (perhaps with the expectation that it will be part of a future standard), it is free to do so as long as it produces the required diagnostic. If a compiler autodetects Java, or C++, or Python, and chooses to produce an "appropriate" executable, that is outside of the C standard because the program is *not a C program* and the programmer has been informed of that fact.

For larger integers, the message produced by clang and gcc is

> error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type

and no executable is produced. This also complies with the standard, with somewhat less controversy.

Answer (score 2):

In that case a constraint<sup>1</sup> is violated.

Each constant must have a type<sup>2</sup>.

In your example the constant 18446744073709551615 cannot be represented in either int, long int, or long long int, as is specified<sup>3</sup> for decimal constants without a suffix. In that case the constant doesn't have a type<sup>4</sup>, violating the constraint mentioned<sup>2</sup> above.

If a constraint is violated the compiler must produce a warning or an error message<sup>5</sup>.

While this technically isn't undefined behavior, the compiler shouldn't be allowed to continue compiling and produce an executable. Most compilers will, rightfully so, stop compiling such code.

---

(Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x)

<sup>1</sup> (3. Terms, definitions, and symbols 3.8 constraint 1)
 restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is
to be interpreted

<sup>2</sup> (6.4.4 Constants 2)
Each constant shall have a type

<sup>3</sup> (6.4.4.1 Integer constants 5)
The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
be represented.

<sup>4</sup> (6.4.4.1 Integer constants 6)
If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in
its list and has no extended integer type, then the integer constant has no type.

<sup>5</sup> ( 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics 1)
A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
specified as undefined or implementation-defined.

Comment: So the conversion in this case is implementation-defined. right ? and the compiler is giving a warning not an error.

Comment: So summarizing, this is **UB**. Did not get your `If the compilation process isn't stopped,`

Comment: @Sabrina It means: if you somehow convince the compiler to not give an error, and produce an executable.

Comment: In my case it is UB. I feel like you are afraid to say that explicitly.

Comment: My english is not so good honestly maybe you explained it very well but I found problems in understanding it completeley. I will appreciate your patience with me. So if I write that code and I get an executable file with a warning does it mean it is UB or not ?

Comment: Of course if I write the program I will compile and I cannot stop the compiler for doing its job till it finish. So I need to correct that thing.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Gnu compiler I am using

Comment: You should compile with at least these flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. If you do, the compiler will stop at the appropriate time.

Comment: I don't think `-Werror` will be a problem. Sometimes I got warning that are not importants. I just wanted to know if the code is UB or not.

Comment: @Sabrina All warnings are important. You should not ignore them.

Comment: Your note 6 only applies outside of constraints, but this is a constraint. Annoyingly, the standard doesn't actually say that constraint violations are also UB (but IMO there is no other reasonable interpretation)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137418/discussion-on-answer-by-2501-integer-constant-not-in-the-representable-range).