# Braced Initialization Error with 32bit GCC for Unsigned Long Long

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, 32bit-64bit

When I compile the code

```
 typedef long long unsigned myuint64;
 myuint64 a[2] = {18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615}; // error on 32bit gcc
 myuint64 b = 18446744073709551615; // no error
```

on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c18G4rc6a) with ARM32-GCC I get the **errors**

```
(3 warnings for "integer constant is so large that it is unsigned")

error: narrowing conversion of '-1' from 'long long int' to 'myuint64' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wnarrowing]
    6 |  myuint64 a[2] = {18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615};
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: narrowing conversion of '-1' from 'long long int' to 'myuint64' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} [-Wnarrowing]
    6 |  myuint64 a[2] = {18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615};
```

(The number is the maximum value for uint64)

I do not get this error when using ARM64-GCC (or 32bit/64bit Clang or 32bit/64bit MSVC).
But I get the error when using other 32bit GCC variants on Godbolt.

**Why is this an error with these 32bit GCC compilers only?**

I can fix it by using `18446744073709551615u`. **Is there any other way to fix this error** without changing the code and without disabling this warning/error in general (`-Wno-narrowing`)?

Comment: Add postfix `ul` (or `UL`) to make it an unsigned long , e.g. `18446744073709551615ul `. And the numbers are too big to fit into 32 bits anyway so is your myuint64 really 64 bit? 
Have you tried : [std::uint64_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have tried `static_assert(sizeof(myuint64) == sizeof(std::uint64_t), "not 64bit size");` and `static_assert(sizeof(myuint64)*8 == 64, "not 64bit size");` and both is fine.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It does produce *warnings* for `a` and `b`. But in my case here, I also get **errors** for `a`.

Comment: [Pro Tip] Don't use magic numbers, use `myuint64 a[2] = {std::numeric_limits<myuint64>::max(), std::numeric_limits<myuint64>::max()}; ` instead, [it compiles for everyone](https://godbolt.org/z/91oG36voY)

Comment: [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) is more paranoid than direct initialization and rejects some types of implicit conversions.

Comment: @user4581301 Which ofcourse is the whole idea behind list initialization :)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Nah. I think most of the point is to be able to initialize with lists. The added paranoia is to prevent mistakes while initializing with lists.

Comment: Haha, I was refering to the (as you perfectly put it) paranoia part :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether your code compiles or not depends on whether `__int128` exists, and it only exists for ARM64 GCC. The reason is that when you write an *integer-literal* with no suffix such as `u`, the compiler chooses a type from this list until the value fits in one of these types:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`
- some implementation-defined *extended signed integer* type, e.g. `__int128`

*See [[lex.icon] §3](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#3)*.

Your value `18446744073709551615` equals **2<sup>64</sup>-1**, so a 64-bit signed integer cannot fit it, but `__int128` can.

Let's reveal what type ARM64 gcc gives to your integer literal:

```cpp
// warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
void foo(decltype(18446744073709551615)) {}
```

```
foo(__int128):
        ret
```

The warning message doesn't match what really happens: You can see that the compiler outputs a function accepting `__int128`, which is the type of your literal.

The same code compiled with ARM gcc (32-bit) produces:

```cpp
foo(long long):
        bx lr
```

In this case, the literal is too large to fit any of the types, `__int128` doesn't exist (and attempting to use it would produce a compiler error), and GCC chooses to treat this as a warning, not an error.

#### Why your code only works with 64-bit compilers

```cpp
myuint64 a[2] = {18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615};
```

GCC falsely chooses `long long` for your literals even though this code is ill-formed, and converts them to `-1`. `myuint64` is unsigned, so it cannot represent `-1`, and list initialization does not allow narrowing conversion. As a result, we get a compiler error.

With `__int128` on a 64-bit compiler, this is not a problem, because we can convert `__int128(18446744073709551615)` to `myuint64(18446744073709551615)` just fine.

#### Conclusion

You have discovered an unusual situation where compiler diagnostics are really counter-intuitive. Ignoring these diagnostics and understanding that `__int128` is involved reveals the problem.

I am not aware of any compiler flags that you can use to fix this, so I recommend using the `u` suffix for literals, in which case the compiler chooses from:

- `unsigned int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `unsigned long long int`
- some implementation-defined *extended unsigned integer* type, e.g. `__uint128`

Comment: `GCC falsely chooses long long for your literals even though this code is ill-formed` Sounds like gcc is to blame. What gcc does is fine - produces a diagnostic, decides to compile with implementation-specific behavior. `GCC doesn't to comply with the standard` Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637257/integer-constant-not-in-the-representable-range .

Comment: @KamilCuk you're right, the compiler is allowed to accept ill-formed programs as long as it issues some diagnostic. I've misremembered that, it's fixed via edit now.

Comment: @JanSchultke Thank you, that's very interesting. Do I understand correctly that the compiler behaviour in such cases is implementation-specific? I noticed MSVC and Clang are doing `void foo(unsigned __int64)`. I also would have expected the error for variable `b` too.

Comment: @mh333 yes, I've also noticed that clang handles this strangely too. If clang doesn't have a wider type for `18446744073709551615` than `__int64`, then the program is ill-formed. This means that whatever clang is doing is non-standard C++. Strangely, both clang and gcc emit a warning that tells you that `18446744073709551615` is "so large that it's unsigned", but they don't actually turn it into an unsigned type. This might be worth a bug report.