# What is the difference between a constraint (restriction) and a "shall not" (prohibition)?

Tags: c, constraints, language-lawyer, terminology

The C standard describes basically two terms when anything should not or is prohibited to do or is to be fulfilled in C.

A "shall not" which is to be interpreted as prohibition and a constraint which is a restriction.

What I found in ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18) is

> **3.8**
>
> 1 constraint
>
> restriction, either syntactic or semantic, by which the exposition of language elements is to be interpreted.

and

> **4.  Conformance**
>
> 1 In this document, "shall" is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, "shall not" is to be interpreted as a prohibition.
>
> 2 If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this document by the words "undefined behavior" or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe "behavior that is undefined".

but I don't understand the difference. I can read that a constraint is a syntactic or semantic restriction and that a "shall not" is to be interpreted as prohibition. But unfortunately it doesn't make *click* in my head to see now where the difference really is. Prohibition vs. Restriction.

Where is the difference between them two, a *constraint* and a *"shall not" prohibition*?

Also following the line:

> If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

How can a prohibition ("shall not") appear inside or outside of a restriction (constraint)?

---

I've read the answers to this question:

[What are the Constraints in Standard C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33409241/12139179)

with especially [this elaborate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416157/12139179) which I find helpful but anyhow it starts at a logic point at which I am not currently are and does not answer the question where the difference between a *constraint*  and a *"shall not" prohibition* is.

In short: I'm not be able to follow the meaning of this answer because I don't understand where it does build up on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The first couple of paragraphs of the answer to which you linked seem to be devoted specifically to your present question.  If they in fact do not speak to you where you are, then I think I need a better idea of where you are before I could essay a helpful response.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The problem is to find out what a "shall not" (a prohibition) has to do with a constraint and what the difference between them two is. That's what the answer didn't covered. - Going that line further,  Is a "shall not" violation automatically a constraint violation? But the quote says that a "shall not" can also appear outside of a constraint, and thus it is UB. I'm missing the bond and the difference between them two and a solid base for understanding.

Comment: The answer says: "Are the constraints everything that appears in the sections titled Constraints? [...] yes. Is every requirement that is stated outside of those sections not a constraint? [...] yes". What does that fail to cover?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having problems because you're analyzing the definition of "constraint" outside of context.

§3.8 defines terms used in the document. If you read the document, you'll see that "constraint" is always used as a heading (as "Constraints"), and the text under that heading consists entirely of requirements and prohibitions.

So,

- A constraint is an element in a document section titled "Constraints". It will consist of a requirement or a prohibition. The glossary's entry for "constraint" (§3.8) simply gives an idea of what you'll find in these sections.
- "Shall" and "shall not" are respectively requirements and prohibitions.
- Requirements and prohibitions in constraint sections are limits on conforming implementations.

Comment: So "shall" and "shall not"s can be inside of/part of constraints. Following the line "*If a "shall" or "shall not" requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.*" - When do I know whether a "shall not" or "shall" is inside a constraint and when outside? How can I identify a constraint? Only at the stated constraints in the specific sections?

Comment: Re "*How can I identify a constraint?*", A constraint is an element in a document section titled "Constraints".

Comment: Re "*When do I know whether a "shall not" or "shall" is inside a constraint and when outside?*",  If it's not in a section titled "Constraints", it's not in a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints impose requirements on the application; they give allowances to the implementation (to reject the program that violates them).

"Shall" or "shall not" can impose requirements either on the implementation or the application, depending on where they appear. When applied to the application, they can appear as part of the constraints (where they impose a requirement that the implementation issue a diagnostic and an allowance that it reject the program) or anywhere else (where failure to meet them produces undefined behavior).

Where "shall" or "shall not" impose requirements on the implementation, they give allowances to the application to assume that the mandated conditions are met.

Comment: The OP seems to be inquiring about how to recognize those requirements that constitute constraints for the purposes of paragraph 4/2 of the C18 specification.  I'm not seeing how this answer responds to that.